# Constraint layout not showing image from ImageView when app run

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to add some Images by ImageView in Android Activity(ConstraintLayout),
on Android Studio Preview screen, it's showing images correctly, but when I am running the app on real device or emulator, it's not showing the image.

Below is the code which I am using,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vchamps.android.staffast.ProfessionalsCalc"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guidelineVertical1"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="39dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guidelineVertical2"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="96dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guidelineHorizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="87dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="87dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/imgRate"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/rates_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/rates_icon_size"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_rates"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineHorizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineVertical1"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/imgSchedule"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/rates_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/rates_icon_size"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_schedule"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgRate"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineVertical1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/imgPayout"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineVertical1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_payout"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgSchedule"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRate"
        style="@style/fontRateScreenTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="Industry Leading Rates"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineVertical2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineHorizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSchedule"
        style="@style/fontRateScreenTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Flexible Schedule"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineVertical2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvRate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPayout"
        style="@style/fontRateScreenTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Quick and Easy Payout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineVertical2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvSchedule" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnWork"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="CLICK ME"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The UI Preview in Android Studio is as below,

[image: UI Preview]

We can see that 3 Images are getting displayed here,

But when I run the application on emulator or on real device, it's not showing any of 3 images. Below is the screenshot of the emulator,

[image: Emulator View]

- Value of @dimen/rates_icon_size: 36dp
- Three Images Dimensions,

  1. icon_rates : 87x59 Pixels
  2. icon_schedule : 88x78 Pixels
  3. icon_payout : 60x82 Pixels

Please help me by providing resolution of the query, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. Please make sure you are call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`before `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` in your java class. I solved it in this way.

Comment: Yes, I already have called it in same way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In ImageView instead of using srcCompact use src

```
   <ImageView
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/imgRate"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/rates_icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/rates_icon_size"
    app:src="@drawable/icon_rates"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineHorizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineVertical1"
    />
```

instead of

```
    <ImageView
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/imgRate"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/rates_icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/rates_icon_size"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_rates"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineHorizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineVertical1"
    />
```

Comment: but why?! drag n drop actually made it app:srcCompat :( In addition when using vector drawable one needs to use app:srcCompat

Comment: Bro! Thank you so very much, I literally have been held back by this one issue. Any idea why this is the reason?

Comment: @Chris-Jr i think you can use `srcCompat` in `AppCompatImageView` instead of the imageView. I am not sure about the reason.

Comment: @Anmol Ok, that's a fair assumption.

Answer (score 3):

use `android:src="@drawable/icon_rates"` sometime `app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_rates"` not work.

```
<ImageView
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/imgRate"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/rates_icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/rates_icon_size"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_rates"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineHorizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineVertical1"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your images are the problem. At least it's not a elegant solution.

If your app should run on different devices then you should use **Android Vector Drawables** instead of normal **PNG** images.  Using vector drawables instead of bitmaps reduces the size of your APK because the same file can be resized for different screen densities without loss of image quality.

If you want to use your images then you should convert them first in the SVG format (with Inkscape for example it's for free) and then in the Vector Drawable format with [this](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) free online tool.

The second solution would be to use [Material Design Icons](https://material.io/icons/). They are developed with many designers to ensure a good user experience and they are also available in the vector drawable format.

I tryed your code out with the vector drawables and the app is displaying the images without problems.