# Android - Constraint Layout inside another Constraint Layout background not showing

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an Android activity in which I want to have a header, and the content below the header. I want to have background image that is streched just on the content, but not on the header.

[image]

From the picture you can see that my image is streched also on the logo part of the screen, which I don't want.

Here is the xml of my current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_11"
    tools:context=".login.LoginActivity"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="381dp"
        android:layout_height="156dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-480dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emptyImage"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="445dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/TICK_BACKGROUND"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_usernameTextField"
        android:layout_width="291dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_text_edit_shape"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/INPUT_TEXT_COLOR"
        android:textColorHint="@color/iron"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_passwordTextField"
        android:layout_width="291dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-38dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_text_edit_shape"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/INPUT_TEXT_COLOR"
        android:textColorHint="@color/iron"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_usernameTextField"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_loginButton"
        android:onClick="loginButtonClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_shape"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_passwordTextField"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.28"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I thought about making a parent Layout and inside that Layout add a header and another layout that contains the content. And then set the background inside the content layout like like this: `android:background="@drawable/background_11"`

Here is the code I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">




    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, my background is not showing up. Here are the reuslts:
[image]

Comment: [hello sir. may be help you. this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715050/constraint-layout-not-showing-image-from-imageview-when-app-run)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a ConstraintLayout in an other ConstraintLayout but you need to respect some rules. All direct childs of a ConstraintLayout should have constraint on left,top, right and bottom.

I think that without the constraint left and right of your inner ConstraintLayout, he have a width and height equals to 0dp , he is not displayed.

Have you try to add constraint left and rigth to your inner ConstraintLayout ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by making a constraint layout inside the Linear Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/netset_logo_2" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/background_11">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Still I don't understand why doesn't my first solution work. Why can't you add a constraint layout inside the constraint layout?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem adding a constraint layout inside of another constraint layout if you satisfy all constraints.

This would work:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_11"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But also:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_11"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If it is the right approach using a ConstraintLayout for the purpose of setting a background image is another question.

Since you are only using the ConstraintLayout to use the background property, you can skip that layout completely and use a View directly.
Since all views inherit from View, but just add a lot of logic on top of it, in this use case a View is enough to satisfy the needs.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_11"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
</View>
```

Answer (score -2):

Well naturally, you made the constraint layout take the entire screen, and the Logo take a smaller subset of it.
so you have the logo on your screen, and beneath it the background.
you might want to set the "background" on a different sub layout inside the main constraint layout.

something like this

```
<constraintlayout
width:match_parent
height:match_parent>
    <logo here/>
    <constraintlayout
    background_here>
    <constraintlayout/>
<constraintlayout/>
```

hope it makes sense.